# definition of cokernel in category theory

Tags: abelian-categories

In additive category $C$,we define the kernel of a morphism  $ f:A → B $ (if it exists),  $kerf$ represents the functor $ ker(f_∗: Hom(?,A) →  Hom(?,B)).$
That is : $$kerf_* → Hom(?,A) → Hom(?,B) $$   in $Fun(C,Sets)$.
Complete the sequence and we get : $$kerf_* → Hom(?,A) → Hom(?,B) → cokf_*.$$
Dually, $cokf$ is defined as corepresenting the functor  $$ker(f^∗: Hom(B,?) → Hom(A,?)).$$

Here is my question : Why don`t we define $cokf$ representing the functor $cokf_*$?
And is there any connection between $cokf_*$ and $cokf$?

P.S My professor told me maybe the reason lies in the property of left exactness of Hom functor.